# How to represent currency in Go?

Tags: go, currency

What is the correct way to store and do arithmetic on currency in Go? There doesn't seem to be a corresponding decimal type and using floats is a big no.

Comment: Have you tried [math.big](http://golang.org/pkg/math/big/) with your own fix-point arithmetic on top?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'd say a way to go is to store amounts of money using properly sized integer type, normalized to the lowest possible amount. Say, if you need to store amounts in US dollars down to one cent, multiply your values by 100 and hence store them in full cents.

Another way is to implement a custom type which would model what is "decimal" in some other languages, that is, it would use two integer numbers to represent amount of money.

Comment: I like that idea. Define a struct with two integers, the whole and decimal numbers, then you can declare custom methods for your currency type, including conversions, etc.

Comment: JFTR, packages which implement fixed-point decimal numbers—suitable for currency calculations—for Go do exist; one example is [`github.com/shopspring/decimal`](https://github.com/shopspring/decimal).

Comment: how about using `math/big`: https://pkg.go.dev/math/big?
@kostix

Comment: @0xedb, floating-point numbers provided by `math/big` [are still base-2](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Float) — they just allow for "practically infinite" (bounded by available computation resources) precision and magnitude. The packages providing support for "decimal" floating-point numbers work with base-10. To get the basic idea of why this is useful when working with monetary values, please read [this](https://github.com/shopspring/decimal#why-dont-you-just-use-float64).

Comment: @0xedb, another point is that "normal" floating-point numbers were invented as a means to be able to represent values in a huge range of magnitudes using modest amount of memory (basically something like \[10^-127…10^127\] for single-precision (32-bit) floats). Because of the requirement of efficacy and the general application target being scientific calculations, FP values are base-2. But when we work with monetary values, we do not need insane ranges of magnitude (even when working with things like GDP or sovereign debt) and would like to use base-10 for 100% precise calculations.

Comment: @0xedb, I would recommend ["Code" by Charles Petzold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code:_The_Hidden_Language_of_Computer_Hardware_and_Software) as the best intro to floating-point numbers I've ever read (I consider the whole book as a must-read for IT folks).

Comment: @kostix OK got it. I'll check out the book too.

Comment: Also worth checking out: <https://github.com/robaho/fixed>

Answer (score 15):

This seems like a great opportunity to create a type, which stores the value in a safe and precise integer-based way, but gives you extra behavior you'd want from a decimal type.  For instance, a quick implementation might look like this (https://play.golang.org/p/nYbLiadQOc):

```
// USD represents US dollar amount in terms of cents
type USD int64

// ToUSD converts a float64 to USD
// e.g. 1.23 to $1.23, 1.345 to $1.35
func ToUSD(f float64) USD {
    return USD((f * 100) + 0.5)
}

// Float64 converts a USD to float64
func (m USD) Float64() float64 {
    x := float64(m)
    x = x / 100
    return x
}

// Multiply safely multiplies a USD value by a float64, rounding
// to the nearest cent.
func (m USD) Multiply(f float64) USD {
    x := (float64(m) * f) + 0.5
    return USD(x)
}

// String returns a formatted USD value
func (m USD) String() string {
    x := float64(m)
    x = x / 100
    return fmt.Sprintf("$%.2f", x)
}
```

The given type behaves the way one might expect, especially given tricky use-cases.

```
fmt.Println("Product costs $9.09. Tax is 9.75%.")

f := 9.09
t := 0.0975
ft := f * t
fmt.Printf("Floats: %.18f * %.18f = %.18f\n", f, t, ft)

u := ToUSD(9.09)
ut := u.Multiply(t)
fmt.Printf("USD:    %v * %v = %v\n", u, t, ut)
```

> Product costs $9.09. Tax is 9.75%.
>
> Floats: 9.089999999999999858 * 0.097500000000000003 = 0.886275000000000035
>
> USD:    $9.09 * 0.0975 = $0.89

Answer (score 10):

Rational numbers are quite a good solution for representing money values. That is, a type that has a numerator and a denominator.

Often monetary data structures are overly complex - Java's BigDecimal being an example. A more mathematically-consistent approach is to define a type that handles rational numbers. When 64bit integers are used, a huge range of numbers can be accurately and efficiently represented. Errors and rounding issues are less of a problem than for any solution that needs to convert binary fractions to/from decimal fractions.

Edit: The Go standard library includes [arbitrary-precision integers and rational numbers](http://golang.org/pkg/math/big/). The Rat type will work well for currency, especially for those cases that require arbitrary precision, e.g. foreign exchange. Here's [an example](http://play.golang.org/p/vQ6hT-zcYt).

Edit 2: I have used the `decimal.Decimal` [Shopspring package](https://github.com/shopspring/decimal) extensively. Under the hood, this combines `big.Int` with an exponent to provide a fixed-point decimal with a nearly-unlimited range of values. The `Decimal` type is a rational number where the denominator is always a power of ten, which works very well in practice.

Answer (score 5):

There are actually [a few packages](http://godoc.org/?q=decimal) implementing a decimal type, though there's no clear leader among them.

Comment: Looks like there is a clear leader by now:
https://github.com/shopspring/decimal

Answer (score 0):

for me the best options is store data as int representing cents of EUR and then use one of this to show:

```
func CentsToEuros(cents int) string {
  euros := float64(cents) / 100.0
  return fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", euros)
}

func CentsToEurosItalianView(cents int) string {

  it := language.Italian
  printer := message.NewPrinter(it)
  euros := float64(cents) / 100.0
  return printer.Sprintf("%.2f", euros)

}

func CentsToEurosItalianViewWithCurrency(cents int) string {
  eur := currency.EUR
  it := language.Italian
  printer := message.NewPrinter(it)
  euros := float64(cents) / 100.0
  amount := eur.Amount(euros)
  return printer.Sprint(amount)
}





concurrencyUtils_test.go:7: ###################### CentsToEuros ######################
concurrencyUtils_test.go:11: value  1  result  0.01
concurrencyUtils_test.go:11: value  2  result  0.02
concurrencyUtils_test.go:11: value  3  result  0.03
concurrencyUtils_test.go:11: value  50  result  0.50
concurrencyUtils_test.go:11: value  500  result  5.00
concurrencyUtils_test.go:11: value  5000  result  50.00
concurrencyUtils_test.go:11: value  100200050  result  1002000.50
concurrencyUtils_test.go:11: value  5  result  0.05
concurrencyUtils_test.go:14: ###################### CentsToEurosItalianViews ######################
concurrencyUtils_test.go:17: value  1  result  0,01
concurrencyUtils_test.go:17: value  2  result  0,02
concurrencyUtils_test.go:17: value  3  result  0,03
concurrencyUtils_test.go:17: value  50  result  0,50
concurrencyUtils_test.go:17: value  500  result  5,00
concurrencyUtils_test.go:17: value  5000  result  50,00
concurrencyUtils_test.go:17: value  100200050  result  1.002.000,50
concurrencyUtils_test.go:17: value  5  result  0,05
concurrencyUtils_test.go:20: ###################### CentsToEurosItalianViews ######################
concurrencyUtils_test.go:23: value  1  result  EUR 0,01
concurrencyUtils_test.go:23: value  2  result  EUR 0,02
concurrencyUtils_test.go:23: value  3  result  EUR 0,03
concurrencyUtils_test.go:23: value  50  result  EUR 0,50
concurrencyUtils_test.go:23: value  500  result  EUR 5,00
concurrencyUtils_test.go:23: value  5000  result  EUR 50,00
concurrencyUtils_test.go:23: value  100200050  result  EUR 1.002.000,50
concurrencyUtils_test.go:23: value  5  result  EUR 0,05
```

--- PASS: TestCentsToEuros (0.00s)
PASS

Process finished with the exit code 0